# What is the best way to buy bulk bricks ONLY?

Tags: shopping

I've been finding that most bulk lots on eBay and the like tend to be mixed LEGO. I'd really like to buy lots with bricks (2x2, 2x4 preferrably) ONLY. Where can I look, what search terms can I use, and what strategies can I employ to get the best deals?

Comment: Have you checked out a Lego re-seller like Bricks and Minifigs?